# Differences between ping and ping -c 3 option

Tags: google, ping

I would like to know what the differences between using the commands :

```
ping -c 3 www.google.com
```

**and**

```
ping www.google.com
```

Any help or information is appreciated. 
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ping -c` option will specify the number of packets sent and will stop after counting them , here in you example count is 3 .

[image]

```
ping www.google.com
```

will send infinite packets until you stop it by closing or ctrl+c

For more information about ping options

[Ping Options](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm)

Or use `man ping` in terminal .

Try it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ping -c 3 www.google.com
```

will send exactly three ping requests to Google, after which the program terminates. It doesn't matter whether there are replys for (some of) the requests or not.

```
ping www.google.com
```

will endlessly send ping requests to Google, and the ping command will never terminate until you end it manually using, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.